# Sound Effects/Manipulation?

Tags: java, android

I am creating an android app that basically records an applies an "Effect" on the audio track then plays it back.  I got my app to record an play back but I am stuck an not sure where do go from here.  I have been Googling for days now trying to find a open source audio library or some way to change the audio after I record it.  I currently have it setup to play back using SoundPool an I't lets me speed up an slow down the audio.  I would like to do things like change pitch an add echo etc.  I will appreciate any responses because I am totally stumped right now.

Thanks
Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked into the Java Sound API? It looks like it can do some of what you want.

Comment: Java Sound API isn't implemented in Android, and it's not planned: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60

Comment: So is there any possible way to do audio manipulation on the android platform?

Thanks
Adam