# How to add sound effects on Android?

Tags: java, android, audio

I would like to write an App, that picks up sound from the mic, adds effects to it and plays it back in realtime.

If found [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) to pick up sound from the mic and [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html) to play it back. In between, I need some library to manipulate the sound, add effects or use some equalizer on it. This maybe achieved with the Java Sound API, but that seems to be missing as I read [in this issue report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60) pointed to from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971463/sound-effects-manipulation).

My question is: How can I do this on Android? Can you recommand any libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Quick google search http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html. It seems you can add effects using this class

Comment: That doesn't look very useful since it only load samples and does not support streaming from mic to speaker. Besides that, the only effect is to change the playback rate or do I miss something here?